# Can't set array values through iterator

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

using python 3.4

```
ranks = [[0 for y in range(0,len(graph))] for x in range(0,iterSites)]
for site in ranks[0]:
    site = 2
print(ranks)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Why does "site = 2" not set every value of ranks[0] to 2?

Comment: `ranks[0] = [2] * len(ranks[0])`

Comment: And ... you don't need a comprehension to build the original list: ```ranks = [[0]*len(graph)]*len(iterSites)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because site is a copy of ranks[0][x] not the real value .  What you have to do is something like:

```
for site in range(len(ranks[0])):
    ranks[0][site] = 2
print(ranks)
```

Comment: Please look at @anirudh answer it's exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

site is a local variable, whose value will not be assigned to the value of the list. Change the code as shown below:

```
ranks = [[0 for y in range(0,len(graph))] for x in range(0,iterSites)]
for site in range(len(ranks[0])):
    ranks[0][site] = 2
print(ranks)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you are doing `site = 2` while you need to update `rank`

second `ranks[0]` is a list not a cell inside a list, so your iteration is not right.

You can change you code as follows:

```
ranks = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

for idx, value in enumerate(ranks[0][:]):
    ranks[0][idx] = 2

print ranks
```

**Output:**

```
[[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```